# ошибка в Python IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, pycharm

в коде выдает ошибку IndexError: list index out of range в строке  a[i].append(i - j), помогите понять, пожалуйста, почему и как это исправить

```
a = []
for i in range(1, 5):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(1, 5):
      if i == j:
          a[i].append(i - j)
      else:
          a[i].append(i - 2 * j)
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(1, 5):
        print("%3d" % a[i][j], end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Индексация списков в Питоне идёт с нуля. Когда вы первый раз делаете `a.append([])` - у вас добавится элемент с индексом `0`. А дальше вы делаете `a[i].append(...)`, при том что у вас `range()` от `1`, т.е. вы обращаетесь к элементу с индексом `1`, которого еще не существует.

Так что, либо каждый раз вычитать из индексов единицу.

```
a = []
for i in range(1, 5):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(1, 5):
      if i == j:
          a[i-1].append(i - j)
      else:
          a[i-1].append(i - 2 * j)
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(1, 5):
        print("%3d" % a[i-1][j-1], end=' ')
    print()
```

Либо переделать на индексацию с нуля (и формулы поменять если потребуется, т.к. `i` и `j` уже другие):

```
a = []
for i in range(4):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(4):
      if i == j:
          a[i].append(i - j)
      else:
          a[i].append(i - 2 * j - 1)  # << формула поменена
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        print("%3d" % a[i][j], end=' ')
    print()
```